# Custom date format and filtering question in Excel

Tags: excel, date, filter, format

I have a date column in Excel but the date could be pasted in 4 different formats in that column

20200423  -full year/month/day    or
202004 - just year/month    or
2020  - just year
or   no date

For presentation I need the first two to have a hyphen in the right place - 2020-04-23  and 2020-04 and the third one with no formatting, just the year 2020

and when I click on the filter button the filter for that column should only show the years at the top level, then you click on the + button for all the subhierarchy month/day details.

I'm told the first part might be done using the Conditional Formatting feature, which I have never used.  When I try using Format Cells on that column and select Custom yyyy-mm-dd it works for the first two but converts 2020 to 1905-07-12.

Can this even be done in one column or am I aiming a bit high?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can't be done in one column.  I figured out how to format the date entry by adding a new rule in Conditional Formatting, which formats based on the length of the entry.  But I'm generating an additional column from the original SQL query that contains the YEAR portion, so the end-user can filter on that column.  Because trying to filter on the formatted column will bring up a slew of entries instead of just the year.